# Cannot delete failed pod in Kubernetes Dashboard

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I'm trying to delete a failed pod from the `Pods` page on the Kubernetes Web UI, but it is not getting deleted.

I understand what the error itself is, and I believe I have resolved it by using `secrets`, since this is a private repo. That said, I cannot re-add the pod again correctly, since it already exists.

Here is what I am seeing on the `Pods` page in the Kubernetes UI:

**Pod Status:** `Waiting: ContainerCreating`

**Error**:

```
Failed to pull image "<USERNAME>/<REPO>:<TAG>": 
failed to run [fetch --no-store docker://<USERNAME>/<REPO>:<TAG>]: 
exit status 254 stdout: stderr: Flag --no-store has been deprecated, 
please use --pull-policy=update fetch: Unexpected HTTP code: 401, URL: https://xxxxxx.docker.io/v2/<USERNAME>/<NAMESPACE>/manifests/<TAG>
    Error syncing pod
```

I have also tried deleting the pod with `kubectl`, but `kubectl` can't even see the failed pod!

```
$ kubectl get pods
No resources found
$ kubectl get pods --show-all
No resources found
```

Is there any other way that I can delete this pod?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found a solution to my own problem. Go to the `Workloads` page in the Kubernetes Web UI, and delete the associated `Deployment`, and the `Pod` will be deleted as well.

If the pod does not get deleted after this, you will need to force a delete from the command line.

`kubectl delete pod <POD_NAME> --grace-period=0 --force`

Answer (score 2):

Use command below to delete terminated or failed one:

`kubectl delete pods pod_name --grace-period=0 --force -n namespace_name`